# How to fetch child table specific data when we are selected parent table?

Tags: hibernate

I am working with hibernate criteria ,I have two tables with `one to many` relationship .those are **User** and **Address** .`User` have **one to many relationship** with `Address` table.One `user` have 3 Address like below

**User**

```
userId ---- username ----lastname 

   1  ---      balu   ---- v
```

**Address**

```
AddressId -----    cityName   ------      userId


1  --            vizag    ---         1

2     ----      srikakulam  -----   1

3     ----       hyd         ----  1
```

But I want Result like when I am fetching parent object `User` Instead of fetching all `addressList` for that user **I want only CityName='Hyd'  address object(Instead of fetching all 3 records for child table I want only one record)**.How can I write criteria query for this .Any one help me.

Comment: on what basis you want to select one out of many? like out of the three cities that you have mentioned how would you get to know that you have to select hyd ? Please elaborate..

Comment: I will get know from user selection from UserInterface,For example EndUser select hyd I want to do some operations in that row and persistent on database .Present I am reading user address by using for loop and check if(cityName="UserSelectedValue(Hyd)")I am doing my changes.Now I have 3 records no problem ..but later it may be 100 records also ..that's why I need this .thanks

Comment: just answered your question. Please ask if any further doubt..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it can be realized only by hibernate filters.

see example

entity definition

```
    @Entity
    @FilterDef(name = "filtAddr", parameters = {@ParamDef(name = "cityName", type = "string")})
    public class User {
        @Id
        private Long id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user" )
        @Filter(name = "filtAddr", condition = "city_name = :cityName")
        private List<Address> addresses;
    }

    @Entity
    public class Address {
        @Id
        private Long id;

        private String cityName;

        @ManyToOne
        private User user;
    }
```

and loading data with session filter

```
Filter filter = session.enableFilter("filtAddr");
filter.setParameter("cityName", "Hyd");

List<User> users =  session.createCriteria(User.class)
        .setFetchMode("addresses", FetchMode.JOIN) //optional
        .list();
```

Comment: But why would someone fetch whole parent entity when the change required to be made is only in a child entity. That will unnecessary take more space on heap and and the database call will also take longer time in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your answer to my question, below is the complete scenario and my suggestion to you :) -->

when user selects one of his many addresses from some user interface, then you have to perform some action on that address.

To perform this requirement, you are fetching user using criteria and later iterating in the list of addresses in that user entity to find the match. and then perform required actions on that address and save it.

My Suggestion:  Here instead of fetching User entity, **you could better fetch the Address entity directly using Criteria with Restrictions as (userid=< UserId > and address=< user's selection >)**, this way you'll straight way get the address object and perform any required action in it.

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

Entities returned from database are always returned as a whole, without any filtering on the data. They represent the current state of the database, which means you will always get all addresses.

If you need a specific address, write a separate query for it, or loop through all user's addresses and get the one you want in a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Criteria returns the whole Entity, and there is **no straight way to selectively fetch a child class**.

But the **Database/Entity design could be crafted more wisely to avoid such situations**. Like consider this slight modification to your example:

say, there are 'n' number of addresses that a user can have, but there could be only one address which could be his communication address. Now the situation will be as below -->

**User**

userId ---- username ----lastname --- communicationAddressId

1      ---- balu     ----v        --- 3

**Address**

AddressId ----- cityName ------ userId

1 -- vizag --- 1

2 ---- srikakulam ----- 1

3 ---- hyd ---- 1

Here you can create an entity,say UserWithCommAdressOnly, with oneToOne mapping on comminucationAdderessId and without oneToMany Mapping on Adderess.AdderessId.

This way you can fetch a user by just fetching one address with it.