# Many to Many with condition. How can i add limited entries in list based on condition?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, many-to-many

I'm creating a dynamic menu using spring and hibernate based on user roles. It works fine and menu is getting generated. but the relationship between menu and submenu doesn't work properly. I want only submenus which has roles assigned to them. but it contains all the submenus.

My POJOs are like below.

Menu.java

```
package com.pmc.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;

@Entity
@Table(name="menu", catalog="test")
public class Menu implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "menu_item_id")
    private Integer menuId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="MENU_ROLES",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="menu_item_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_role_id")})
    private List<UserRole> userRoles;
    @Column(name = "label", length = 100)
    private String label;
    @Column(name = "link", length = 100)
    private String link;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent")
    private Menu parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Menu> submenus;


    public Integer getMenuId() {
        return menuId;
    }
    public void setMenuId(Integer menuId) {
        this.menuId = menuId;
    }

    public List<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }
    public void setUserRoles(List<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
    public Menu getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    public void setParent(Menu parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public List<Menu> getSubmenus() {
        return submenus;
    }
    public void setSubmenus(List<Menu> submenus) {
        this.submenus = submenus;
    }



}
```

UserRole.java

```
package com.pmc.domain;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table (name = "roles", catalog = "test")
public class UserRole {

    private Integer userRoleId;
    private Set<User> users;
    private String role;

    private List<Menu> menus;

    public UserRole() {
    }

    public UserRole(Set<User> users, String role) {
        this.users = users;
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_role_id", 
        unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getUserRoleId() {
        return this.userRoleId;
    }

    public void setUserRoleId(Integer userRoleId) {
        this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="USER_ROLES",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_role_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="username")})
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="userRoles",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Menu> getMenus() {
        return menus;
    }

    public void setMenus(List<Menu> menus) {
        this.menus = menus;
    }


}
```

User.java

```
package com.pmc.domain;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="users", catalog="test")
public class User {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public User(String username, String password, 
        boolean enabled, Set<UserRole> userRole) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, 
        nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "password", 
        nullable = false, length = 60)
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    public Set<UserRole> getUserRole() {
        return this.userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(Set<UserRole> userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

}
```

my query is like this.

```
select menu from User user, IN (user.userRole) roles, IN(roles.menus) menu where user.username = ?
```

It gives all the required menus with proper roles to the user. But the list of submenus in each menu is not reflected according to the roles.

Can you please help on this?
Thanks

Comment: Can anyone answer this please?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/26661077/4074715